# What is the difference between which and where

Tags: linux, zsh, shell-builtin, which

What is the difference between `where` and `which` shell commands?
Here are some examples

```
 ~  where cc
/usr/bin/cc
/usr/bin/cc
~  which cc
/usr/bin/cc
```

and

```
  ~  which which
which='alias | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --show-dot --show-tilde'
/usr/bin/which
  ~  which where
/usr/bin/which: no where in (/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/bnikhil/bin:/bin)
```

also

```
  ~  where which
which: aliased to alias | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --show-dot
 --show-tilde
which: shell built-in command
/usr/bin/which
/usr/bin/which
  ~  where where
where: shell built-in command
```

To me it seems that they do the same thing one being a shell builtin, not quite sure how that is different from a command?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`zsh` is one of the few shells (the other ones being `tcsh` (`which` originated as a `csh` script for `csh` users, which also had its limitation, `tcsh` made it a builtin as an improvement)) where `which` does something sensible since it's a shell builtin, but somehow you or your OS (via some `rc` file) broke it by replacing it with a call to the system `which` command which can't do anything sensible reliably since it doesn't have access to the interns of the shell so can't know how that shell interprets a command name.

In zsh, all of [`which`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-which), [`type`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-type), [`whence`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-whence) and [`where`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-where) are builtin commands that are all used to find out about what commands are, but with different outputs. They're all there for historical reason, you can get all of  their behaviours with different flags to the [`whence`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-where) command.

You can get the details of what each does by running:

```
info zsh which
info zsh whence
...
```

Or type `info zsh`, then bring up the index with `i`, and enter the builtin name (completion is available).

And avoid using `/usr/bin/which`. There's no shell nowadays where **that** `which` is needed. As Timothy says, use the builtin that your shell provides for that. Most POSIX shells will have the `type` command, and you can use `command -v` to only get the path of a command (though both `type` and `command -v` are optional in POSIX (but not Unix, and not any longer in LSB), they are available in most if not all the Bourne-like shells you're likely to ever come across).

(BTW, it looks like `/usr/bin` appears twice in your `$PATH`, you could add a `typeset -U path` to your `~/.zshrc`)

Comment: This came up in an earlier question too. To extend this point, you should always use a shell built in command where one exists. So in bash, use "type" instead of "which."

Answer (score 1):

**Difference 1:**

I would like to mention a nice functional difference **I observed from your question itself**:

`which` will list the first path, the passed argument was found.

`where` will list all of the paths, the passed argument was found.

e.g.

```
 ~ which tree
/bin/tree
```

```
 ~ where tree
/bin/tree
/usr/bin/tree
```

---

**Difference 2:**

`where` works not only on Unix, but on Windows as well.